# OutlineInputBorder disappears when the TextFieldForm is selected/focused

Tags: flutter

I am making a login screen and my field for the email looks like the following:

`final email = new TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Email",
        contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
        ),
      ),
    );`

The issue is that when this field is selected by the user to start typing in their email, the outline border goes away. I want it to stay. Is there some other widget I should use, or a way to handle this that I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

use focusedBorder

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.redColor),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.redColor),
          ),
          fillColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
          filled: true,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue.

It seems your theme's accent color and screen's background color are same. Configuring a different color for accent color or background color will be fix your issue.